# Проблема с определением местоположения и расстояния до объектов

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, геолокация

Добрый день. Задача в следующем:

Есть база данных с координатами широты и долготы объектов. При запуске приложения определяется текущее местоположение (широта и долгота). Вокруг текущего местоположения определяется квадратная область, границы которой находятся в заданном в километрах расстоянии от текущего местоположения. Нужно определить какие из объектов в базе попадают в эту область.

У меня такой алгоритм, для границ на расстоянии 5 км до моего местоположения:

1. Получаю свою широту и долготу.
2. Перевожу 5 км в градусы.
3. К своим значениям широты и долготы прибавляю и вычитаю значения 5 км в градусах, чтобы получить границы.
4. В цикле проверяю все координаты объектов в базе, попадают они в заданный диапазон координат или нет.

По координатам все считается правильно и объекты попавшие в эту зону выводятся в отдельный массив. Но когда считаю расстояние до некоторых объектов, то получаю, что оно должно входить в диапазон по километрам, но не входит по градусам.

Код где считаются границы и определяется вхождение элементов массива (индекс 2 в массиве - долгота, индекс 3 - широта):

```
double kmSH = 111.13486 * cos(_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude); // Сколько километров в одном градусе широты
double kmD = 111.13486; // Сколько километров в одном градусе долготы
double maxLatitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude + 5/kmSH; // Верхняя граница широты
double minLatitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude - 5/kmSH; // Нижняя граница широты
double maxLongitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude + 5/kmD; // Верхняя граница долготы
double minLongitude = _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude - 5/kmD; // Нижняя граница долготы

_arrayOfObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < _arrayOfObjects.count; i++) {
    if (([[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue] <= maxLatitude) && ([[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue] >= minLatitude) && ([[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] <= maxLongitude) && ([[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue] >= minLongitude)) {
        [_arrayOfObjectsInArea addObject:[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}
```

Код где определяются расстояния до объектов базы:

```
_arrDistance = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < _arrayOfObjects.count; i++) {
    CLLocation *objectLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue] longitude:[[[_arrayOfObjects objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue]];
    CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:objectLocation];
    [_arrDistance addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", distanceBetween]];
}
```

И вот что получается для координат моего местоположения:

maxLatitude = 55.718345

minLatitude = 55.573046

maxLongitude = 37.718273

minLongitude = 37.628292

Объект с координатами 55.64183957,37.74536162 не входит в эту область и в новый массив не добавляется, но расчет расстояния выдает мне - 4576.159731 метров. 4,5 км меньше 5 км! Проверяла по картам Гугла, расстояние то же считается правильно. То есть и расстояние и координаты считаются верно, но по километрам объект входит в область, а по координатам нет. Как такое может быть??

В чем тут проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Градусы долготы не соответствуют 111 км/штука, это только на экваторе. Сравни Северный полюс - два шага в сторону и на другом полушарии. Точная формула для километража по долготе - 111.13486*cos(широта), а вот градус по широте как раз равен 111.13486. Нужно переставить местами формулы широты и долготы в начале скрипта.

Comment: Поменяла местами, но все равно в новый массив не добавляется. Как было так и осталось..

Comment: Блин, когда меняла местами в конце строки определения километров по долготе получились случайно две точки с запятой. Удалила лишнюю и все заработало)) Видимо за целый день у меня совсем все смешалось, где широта, где долгота, где х, где у... Спасибо большое!